# # of times a single word in a sentence

Tags: java, string

How can i get the # of times a single word is in a given sentence.. String.split cannot be used.. I don't really need the code. I just need an idea to get started..

```
package exam2;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Problem2 {    
    /**
     * @param args
     */    
    public static String input, word, a, b, c;
    public static int index;

    public static void Input() {    
        System.out.println("Enter Sentence: ");
        input = IO.readString();

        System.out.println("Enter Word: ");
        word = IO.readString();    
    }

    public static void Calc() {    
        Input();    
        index = input.indexOf(word);    
        int[] data = new int[input.length()];    
        data[0] = index;

        while (index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Index : " + index);
            for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                data[i] = index;    
            }
            index = input.indexOf(word, index + word.length());    
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {    
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if (data[i] == data[j]) {    
                    a = input.substring(data[i], data[i] + word.length());    
                }    
                else if (data[i] != data[j]) {    
                    b = input.substring(data[i], data[i] + word.length());    
                    c = input.substring(data[j], data[j] + word.length());
                }    
            }    
        }
        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {    
            count++;
        }    
        System.out.println(count);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc();  
    }    
}
```

using a while loop i finding the index of word given by the user in the sentence again given by the user.. I am storing those index in the array. for some reason that is not working.. so i found another way of implementing it. if the index of that word in the array is the equals each other then the word only exits once. I have got this to work.. but if the word exits more than once that is creating the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the first letter of the word given by user.Next look  at the sentence and find the letter.Then check the second letter of the word and compare it with the next letter in sentence . If its same again continue comparing .If not start again from next letter. Each time  you get all the letters of the word and then a space you add 1 to a counter.Think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [String.indexOf(String, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  This finds the next position of the parameter String, starting at the parameter int.

Comment: i have made use of that in the above code but still there is one hiccup that i cannot solve

Answer (score 0):

Split *can't* be used? That seems rather odd. I'll bite though, and say simply that we don't have enough information to give a correct answer.

1. What is a word exactly?
2. How should symbols/letters be considered?
3. When is a sentence completed?
4. Should hyphened words be special?
5. Do we have 1 sentence and we are testing many words?
6. Do we have 1 word and many sentence?
7. What about substring matches (can vs canteen)?

Given what I can guess you should loop through the "sentence" tokenized the input by building "words" until you hit word boundary. Put the found words into a HashMap  (keyed on the word) and increment the value for each word as you find it.

Comment: 1. a word would be any word user input. i have to check and see whether is it the sentence user input and how many times..             2. there are only letter no symbols. there will be a normal sentence and a normal word given by the user..

Comment: i have put together something i would appreciate if you have look at it and provide any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 'input.indexOf(word, fromIndex)' in a loop to find the string. Each time you call this function and it returns something other than -1 increment your count. When it returns -1 or you reach the end of the string stop. fromIndex will start at 0 and will need to be incremented each time you find a string by the length of the string.